# How can I edit the embed when the user reacts? JDA

Tags: java, arrays, filter, discord, discord-jda

When the user reacts, I want to edit the embed to insert the user's nickname into a field.
So I tried to use the onGuildMessageReactionAdd method but it failed. Is there a way?

```
  @Override
    public void onGuildMessageReceived(GuildMessageReceivedEvent event) {
        String[] args = event.getMessage().getContentRaw().split(" ");
        String UserName = Objects.requireNonNull(event.getMember()).getNickname();
        TextChannel textChannel = event.getGuild().getTextChannelById(SendChannelId); 
        if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase(prefix + "test")) {
            EmbedBuilder embed = new EmbedBuilder();
            try {
                embed.setTitle(args[1], "");
            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                embed.addField("testField", "testField", false);
                embed.setFooter("test", Objects.requireNonNull(event.getGuild().getOwner()).getUser().getAvatarUrl());
                event.getChannel().sendMessage(embed.build()).queue();
                embed.clear();
                return;
            }
            embed.addField("...", UserName, false);
            embed.addField("...", "", false); //I want to edit this field!
            embed.addField("...", "", false); 
             try {
                embed.addField("...", args[2], false);
            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                embed.addField("...", "...", false);
            }

            embed.setColor(Color.CYAN);
            embed.setFooter("test", Objects.requireNonNull(event.getGuild().getOwner()).getUser().getAvatarUrl());
            Objects.requireNonNull(textChannel).sendMessage(embed.build()).override(true).queue(message -> {
                message.addReaction("minn:" + emoji1).queue(); //When User react to this emoji
                message.addReaction("minn:" + emoji2).queue();
                temp.push(message.getId());
                target.put(event.getMember().getUser().getId().hashCode(), temp);
                keySet = target.keySet();

            });
            embed.clear();
        }
'''
```

Comment: Would you mind adding the actual code you tried to your question? Right now, one can only assume what went wrong.

Comment: I solved this problem by using ButtonEvent. Sorry for the late reply, and I felt it was difficult to solve it because I couldn't use getMessageId method in the addreaction.